# nUnit : iterate setup for different configs

Tags: nunit, installation, config

In my `[TextFixture]` class I have a `[SetUp]` method that configures various objects ( mock or real ) that are then utilized in my associated test suite of `[Test]` methods.

I'd like to run the same battery of tests multiple times on the objects - where in each run the objects are configured slightly differently ( e.g. different uri forms , different mocked config files settings, etc ).

I'd rather not copy/paste multiple times my entire test class just to accomplish this.

Does nUnit provide a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into parameterized tests
http://nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5

It will let you run the same test with different "input"